# Make right column follow left column

Tags: html, css

I have marked both `div`s with different color. The right column(pink) isn't following the left column(green).

Here is my fiddle: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68m6fymo/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #1b191a;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#leftcolum {
  float: left;
  width: 614px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0C6;
}
#rightcolum {
  float: right;
  width: 286px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #F09;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 6px 0px 8px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftcolum">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etiam congue, elit ut a vivamus mauris erat. At aliquam saepe mauris sit. Aenean vulputate porttitor, cras duis magna, ac sed etiam blandit. Sem eu. Eu nulla mauris aenean magna. Nibh viverra nec ullamcorper cras non justo.
      Sed suscipit fugiat tristique, et pede ante nunc amet, felis gravida nibh placerat, scelerisque sapien fames pede lorem, elit suspendisse mi quam eget. Vitae sed justo nisl vitae nisl, accumsan vitae est. Molestie urna ullamcorper, quis non bibendum.
      Purus mauris eget sed elit nonummy. Vitae amet, mus tempor, turpis donec sodales in, eget lacinia eros eleifend tincidunt non eget. Dui consequat morbi justo sed tincidunt, consequat felis adipiscing, suscipit feugiat porttitor eget quam blandit
      nunc, aliquam morbi aliquam purus, vivamus volutpat adipiscing sed. Elementum placerat donec molestie, iaculis est faucibus ullamcorper. Dui massa leo a fusce iaculis, massa rhoncus ipsum nascetur eleifend vestibulum quam, in aliquam in mattis quisque
      iaculis nisi, id vestibulum lobortis eros tincidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rightcolum">
    <div class="menubg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried for a long time now, using google and so on. Nothing have worked. I'm not a huge fan of `position:absolute`, `relative` and so on. I'm trying to keep the HTML and css simple as possible.

Comment: No fiddle link there.

Comment: I've just added it. I thought it was added, but i have edited the post now

Comment: What do you mean by "following"?

Comment: What do you mean by follow?

Comment: By follow, i mean that the right colum should stretch along with the left colum. You can see i have added box shadow on the right colum and I want the entire div to follow if the left colum expands for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `display: flex;` to `#wrapper` (which makes it a flexbox container)

https://jsfiddle.net/7cb6q238/

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table;` to wrapper css class.

Edit: as johannas said columns should have tablecell atrributes.

Comment: that alone won't help, you'd also have to make the child elements table cells